# Copied the Uniform icons to /usr/share/icons but the tweak tool did not reflect those icons

Tags: icons, gnome-tweak-tool

I extracted the Uniform set of icons to Downloads and from there I copied the  that folder to /usr/share/icons using root privilege. How I did was- I opened the root folder using the command `sudo nautilus` and dragged and dropped the Uniform icons folder to the above mentioned location. The issue is these icons are not reflected in tweak tool for selection.

I even created the .icons folder in Home and extracted the icons to that folder, but that too failed to solve the tweak tool issue

Comment: Did you reboot or re-login after copying the folders?

Comment: For an icon set to be recognized properly as an icon theme, the icons must be properly packed in folders, and an index.theme file must be present. Perhaps your icons were not packed as an icon theme, or you extracted and copied the archive contents in the wrong way.